# Converted audio from mp4 to mp3 cannot be played in Telegram on iOS or Android

Tags: python, ios, mp3, telegram-bot, mp4

I am writing a telegram bot that searches for videos, downloads, converts mp4 to mp3 and throws it to the user. According to the idea, this audio file should be played everywhere. It works fine on the desktop, but it doesn't work on iOS or android.

If you convert mp4 to wav, then this format works on ios and android, but it weighs a lot.

You can advise how to correctly convert mp4 to mp3 (python) so that the audio file is played on any platform.

I use Python.

Answer (score 0):

If Apple/Android don't like MP3, try AAC or OGG?

https://blog.procollabs.com/mp3-alternatives/

Comment: OGG has already tried it. The fact is that it is accepted by telegrams as a voice, which is not exactly what is needed. ACC also tried, but the problem is with the conversion of the file, I may not convert correctly with wav. As I understand it, mp3 has long since gone into the background.

Comment: why are you working with `wav`? Sounds like you're already stripping the audio from the .mp4, so just output in .m4a, no?